# Using glBlitFramebuffer to display a texture

Tags: opengl

I am trying to implement a simple multipass rendering scheme. I first blit the multisampled version of the scene to a FBO `beforeEffectsContext.fbo`. If I then blit this to the application provided FB it works fine. But I want to do another pass on the scene to blur it. I therefore bind the texture in the `COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` in the `beforeEffectsContext.fbo`, sample it, drawing a quad with a blur effect added to another framebuffer `blurContext.fbo`.

If I know display the content of `blurContext.fbo`'s color attachment to the screen using the same approach with a quad and a texture sampling, it works and I get a blurred scene.

But if I try to use `glBlitFramebuffer()` instead in this step, I get a black screeen. The problem seems to be in my misunderstanding of the blitting process and FBOs.

Initialization code for the `blurContext.fbo`:

```
// BeforeEffects Framebuffer
glGenFramebuffers(1, &renderContext->beforeEffectsContext.fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, renderContext->beforeEffectsContext.fbo);

glGenTextures(1, &renderContext->beforeEffectsContext.colorAttachment);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderContext->beforeEffectsContext.colorAttachment);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 800, 600, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, renderContext->beforeEffectsContext.colorAttachment, 0);

// Blur Framebuffer
glGenFramebuffers(1, &renderContext->blurContext.fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, renderContext->blurContext.fbo);

glGenTextures(1, &renderContext->blurContext.colorAttachment);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderContext->blurContext.colorAttachment);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 800, 600, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, renderContext->blurContext.colorAttachment, 0);
```

Rendering:

```
// Draw to the MSampled scene to the BeforeEffects framebuffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, renderContext->multiSamplingContext.fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, renderContext->beforeEffectsContext.fbo);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, 800, 600, 0, 0, 800, 600, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);

// Sample the texture attached to the beforeEffects FBO and draw to the blur FBO
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderContext->beforeEffectsContext.colorAttachment);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, renderContext->blurContext.fbo);
glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);

glUseProgram(renderContext->blurProgramContext.program);
glBindVertexArray(renderContext->vaoBlur);

glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

glUseProgram(0);
glBindVertexArray(0);

// Blit the content of the blur FBO to the app-provided Framebuffer (doesn't work, black screen)
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, renderContext->blurContext.fbo);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_BUFFER, 0);
glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, 800, 600, 0, 0, 800, 600, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT,
    GL_NEAREST);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the line where you are binding the default framebuffer (0) for drawing you have the target as GL_DRAW_BUFFER. According to https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBindFramebuffer.xhtml the correct enum for setting the draw framebuffer is GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER. If you add a call to glGetError you will probably see a GL_INVALID_ENUM error.